# How to setup same shipping rate group of countries

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, table-rates, internationalization

I have set up a Magento shop for my customer. He wants to set up shipping rates for group of countries not individual. 
For eg. all Asia Pacific countries as below

```
weight    Price
1kg       $10
2kg       $15
3kg       $18
```

It would be great if you can help out

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is not such a functionality in Magento. There is no even a linkage between country and the region. Nor even a region entity.

So your options are either create a custom module which will introduce all this functionality (which is rather complex even for an experienced Magento developer) or assign shipping rates manually to each country.

Comment: One more option is to get some shipping rates or shipping rules extension from the magento connect.